# MariaDB 10.8.3 in Docker: can't initialize timers

Tags: docker, mariadb, ubuntu-18.04

This error happens even after clearing the Docker image cache:

```
$ docker run -it --rm mariadb:10.8.3
2022-06-15 11:28:14+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.8.3+maria~jammy started.
2022-06-15 11:28:14+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: mariadbd failed while attempting to check config
        command was: mariadbd --verbose --help --log-bin-index=/tmp/tmp.EUcxIEz4Yz
        Can't initialize timers
```

10.8.3 is currently the `latest` image on Docker Hub. The image tag is `ea81af801379`. This is on 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04. The server has low CPU load, 100+GB of free RAM, and terabytes of free disk space.

I have an existing database that was already touched by this version and that I wouldn't want to risk downgrading.

I have seen [this issue](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22286) but there's no reason that MariaDB would fail to create a thread.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to change the MariaDB version to **avoid** version `10.8.3`, for example by forcing `mariadb:10.8.2` or `mariadb:10.7`, or to set `--security-opt seccomp=unconfined`

If your Dockerfile or docker-compose are referencing `mariadb:latest` or `mariadb:10` in Summer 2022, that's pointing to `mariadb:10.8.3`.

Contrary to the post by @Arno, the Docker version is not the issue.
I am running Docker `20.10.17` and the problem persists.

You can also directly run with an updated security profile:

```
docker run --security-opt seccomp=/etc/docker/profiles-seccomp-scmp-act-trace.json
```

Hopefully a fix will be in the MariaDB `10.8.3` release.

https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/issues/434

Comment: Where do you get the file `/etc/docker/profiles-seccomp-scmp-act-trace.json`?

Answer (score 4):

The issue was reported [on GitHub](https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/issues/434). Upgrading Docker seems to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue running MariaDB (`latest`) on Gitlab CI using [Test Containers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) for Java.

Using the `seccomp=unconfined` security option - as discussed in the Github reported linked by @Arno solved this for me.

Enabling this through `testcontainers-java` is a bit weird, so here's the flow if readers encounter the same issue with Test Containes:

```java
var container = new MariaDBContainer<>("mariadb:latest")
.withCreateContainerCmdModifier(cmd -> {
    var cfg = cmd.getHostConfig();
    List<String> seclist = Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(cfg.getSecurityOpts(),
            LinkedList::new);
    seclist.add("seccomp=unconfined");
    cfg.withSecurityOpts(seclist);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This same question was asked on StackOverflow - please see my response there https://stackoverflow.com/a/72467817

To summarize, your docker version is likely < 20.10.10, which is the minimum required to use Jammy-based images. MariaDB > 10.8.2 uses Jammy, so there's a conflict there.

Upgrading docker is really the only correct option at this point - MariaDB 10.7 ends support soon on 2023-02-14, and Docker 19.03 (the release before 20.10) went EOL on 2021-07-21.